# Se puede hacer y como hacerlo Variable de Instancia (@rooms) en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

La consulta va tengo dos tablas en la base de datos una me da los datos de la reserva como checkin checkout, precio total de la reserva, días de estadía del objeto a reservar  y otra tabla que guarda todo referente al objeto de la reserva en este caso habitación, como metros cuadrado, precio, numero de camas, tipo de capas, etc.

Necesito que toda la información de la habitación, ademas el total a pagar por la estadía de la habitación. la pregunta es ¿cómo puedo yo agregar esa información a la variable de instancia creada en Rails? o no se puede ?.

lo he intentado todo, hice dos array, pero al llevarlo a la vista me muestra el contenido de todas las habitaciones de esa reserva en cada una de las habitaciones en una sola variable de instancia por ejemplo @rooms, intente hacer un hash y colocarlo en una Variable pero solo me guarda solo los registro del ultimo .

Le muestro lo codigos:

Controller:

```
class SummariesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reservation, only: [:index]


  def index    
    @reservations = Reservation.all
    @items = ItemReservation.where(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
    @totals = @items.sum(:total)
    @res = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
    @stay = (Date.parse(@res.checkout) - Date.parse(@res.checkin)).to_i
    @rooms = selected_room
    @ttls = selected_total
    @user = UserReservation.find_by(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
    @other = OtherReservation.where(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
    @sigth = ObsReservation.where(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
  end

  private

  def set_reservation
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
  end


  def selected_room
    @roomsel = []
    @items.each do |item|
      @roomsel << Room.find(item.room_id)
    end
    return @roomsel  
  end

  def selected_total
    @totalsel = []
    @rooms.each do |rooms|
      @totalsel << ItemReservation.find_by(room_id: rooms.id).total
    end
    return @totalsel
     raise
  end
  
end
```

view:

con una idea tonta en hacer un while el cual no resulto

```
<br/> Habitaciones: <br/>
  <% @rooms.each do |rm|%>
  <% cont = 1 %>
  <% while @cont == @rooms.count do %>
    <% @ttls.each do |tt|%>
      <%= tt %>
    <% end %>
    <% @cont = @cont + 1 %>
  <%end%>
  <div clase= "row">
    <div class= "col-sm-12">
      <h4><%= rm.name %></h4>
      <small"> Precio:$ <%= rm.price %> </small>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Metros : <%= rm.meter %>
        </li>
        <li>
          Tipo de Cama: <%= rm.type_bed %>
        </li>
        <li>
          Nº de cama: <%= rm.num_bed %>
        </li>
        <li>
          Descripcion: <%= rm.comment %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class= "col-sm-12 ">
      <div class="row container-fluid">
        <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-center">
          <% if rm.img == "" %>
            <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% else %>
            <%= img_tag rm.img, class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-center">
          <% if rm.img2== "" %>
            <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% else %>
            <%= img_tag rm.img2, class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-center">
          <% if rm.img3 == "" %>
            <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% else %>
            <%= img_tag rm.img3, class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-center">
          <% if rm.img4 == "" %>
            <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% else %>
            <%= img_tag rm.img4, class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me ayuden gracias